# How can you force HTML number input to show more than two decimal places?

Tags: html

So if someone entered 1.00, it would automatically format to 1.0000. Is this built into the numeric input in HTML 5?

Comment: The closest I believe you'll get is `<input type="number" step="0.0001" />`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way that's built into HTML.

However, it's easy enough to do in JavaScript.

```
element.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var value = +this.value;
    if (value === value) this.value = value.toFixed(4);
}, false);
```

Comment: What's the point of checking if value === value? Shouldn't the check be for comparing the variable to this.value?

Comment: @ArturKäpp: `value === value` is only true if `value` is not `NaN` (ie: if `this.value` could be parsed as a number).  `NaN` is unequal to everything, even itself.